# Is there already embedded way inside rapidjson to serialize/deserialize std::pair<float,float>?

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

Is there already embedded way inside rapidjson to serialize/deserialize std::pair ?
I am trying to serialize array of points but without to create custom object(at the moment I serialize in array and x coordinates are on even and y coordinates are on odd positions of array, but more elegant would be array of pairs)